# How to remove GRUB and boot Windows?

Tags: grub2, bootloader

I have tried the other suggestions such as bootrec.exe /FixBoot and bootrec.exe /FixMbr

But on restart it still boots to the grub command line.
I have also tried startup repair using the Windows 7 disk but now I am stuck.
Any ideas?

Comment: Another issue as well it says "This tool can only be run on systems booted using a PC/AT BIOS. This system was booted using EFI or some other firmware type.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the three solutions that have have worked for me.

Boot Linux from a Live cd or usb and make sure you’ve a working Internet connection and type the following on the terminal.

**1. Solution**

```
sudo apt-get install syslinux
```

If the package got installed, use the following command to write the MBR:

```
sudo dd if=/usr/lib/syslinux/mbr.bin of=/dev/sda
```

**2. Solution**

```
sudo apt-get install mbr
```

If the package got installed use following to write the MBR.

```
sudo install-mbr -i n -p D -t 0 /dev/sda
```

***Common for both***

***Replace sda if you want to install the MBR to a different drive. Do not put `sda1`,`sda2`,  or `sda3`. Just put it as `sda` for the hard disk. Finally reboot and your Windows should boot.***

**3. Solution**

**Install Boot-Repair on ubuntu by following steps**

Open the terminal and run the following commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install boot-repair
```

After completing the installation you can launch it from System->Administration->Boot-Repair menu if you use Gnome, or search "boot-repair" in the dash if you use Unity. Then follow the following screenshots:

***Method 1***

- **Click on the advanced options**

[image: Initial screen]

- **Tick the options shown below**

[image: advanced option]

- **Change the tab to Grub Location Tab and Tick The options Shown in the figure**

[image]

**Press Apply and Reboot the system**

***Method 2***

- Select the recommended Boot repair options as shown in the first screenshot

Comment: Still the same issue, Grub doesn't even show up now :/

Comment: try using boot repair.I have updated the answer.btw which windows where you using?was it the newer one having UEFI and windows 8?